# How to use awk method to implement the startsWith function on bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, awk

I'm trying to use awk to implement the startsWith function in bash script, but it is not work.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

```
#! /bin/bash


starts_with()
{
    local string=$1
    local substring=$2
    
    local index=$(printf "%s" "$string" | awk 'BEGIN { print index("$string", "$substring") }')
    
    if [[ "$index" == "1" ]]
    then
        echo "true" : $string : $substring
    else
        echo "false" : $string : $substring
    fi
}

starts_with key1="value" key1=
starts_with key2="value" wrong_key=
```

Here is the output:

```
false : key1=value : key1=
false : key2=value : wrong_key=
```

But the awk page says:

```
index(in, find)

    Search the string in for the first occurrence of the string find, and return the position in characters where that occurrence begins in the string in. Consider the following example:

    $ awk 'BEGIN { print index("peanut", "an") }'
    -| 3

    If find is not found, index() returns zero.

    With BWK awk and gawk, it is a fatal error to use a regexp constant for find. Other implementations allow it, simply treating the regexp constant as an expression meaning ‘$0 ~ /regexp/’. (d.c.)
```

What's wrong in the above `starts_with` function and how to fix?

Comment: See [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in using `awk` when you can do it directly in bash?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
starts_with() {
    local string="$1"
    local substring="$2"

    if [[ $string == "$substring"* ]]
    then
        echo "true : $string : $substring"
    else
        echo "false : $string : $substring"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { print index("$string", "$substring") }'
```

You can not use your shell variables like this in GNU `AWK` command consider simple example

```
string="HELLOWORLD" && awk 'BEGIN{print "$string"}' emptyfile.txt
```

output

```
$string
```

Observe that literal `$string` appeared, use `-v` if you want to ram variable floating in your shell into GNU `AWK` command for example

```
string="HELLOWORLD" && awk -v s=$string 'BEGIN{print s}' emptyfile.txt
```

output

```
HELLOWORLD
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

or export it if you don't mind the extra typing:

```
export string="HELLOWORLD" && mawk '

BEGIN { 
       print ENVIRON["string"]
}'

HELLOWORLD
```

If u don't wanna export, this works too i suppose

```
% string2="HELLOWORLD" mawk '

  BEGIN{ 

    print ENVIRON["string2"] 

  }' | gtee >( gpaste - \
    \
     | gsed -zE 's/^/ orig from pipe :: /' >&2;) | gcat -n       
           
     1  HELLOWORLD
 orig from pipe :: HELLOWORLD
```

I don't know how the clipboard mechanism for Linux and others work, but if you happen to be on `macOS`, and the shell variable you wanna bring in isn't overly complex, here's another method :

```
pbcopy <<<"${TERM_SESSION_ID}" ;

mawk 'BEGIN { 
              (__=" pbpaste ") | getline _;
         close(__) 

print "pasting via macos clipboard ::", (_) }' | lgp3

pasting via macos clipboard :: BEC24EEE-B6B3-4862-A286-1953FB6438A7
```

And if you like your `getline`s to be single statement, then perhaps

```
 mawk ' BEGIN { 
 
   printf(" pasting via macos clipboard :: %*s",
            close((__="pbpaste")|getline _)<"",_) 
 
 }' | lgp3 

 pasting via macos clipboard :: BEC24EEE-B6B3-4862-A286-1953FB6438A7
```